Find the number of terms that are multiple of $4$

If $T_1,T_2,T_3,\cdots,T_n$ form a sequence of real numbers such that $T_1=T_2=1$ and $$T_{n+1}=T_{n-1}\cdot T_n+1$$ for $n\ge2$, find the number of terms in the first $50$ terms of this sequence that are multiple of $4$.

If $T_{n+1}$ is divisible by $4$, then $T_{n-1}\cdot T_n+1$ is also divisible by $4$
It implies that, $T_{n-1}\cdot T_n$ is of the form $4k+3$ where $k$ is a natural number.
This means $T_{n-1}$ is of the form $4k_1+1$ and $T_n$ is of the form $4k_2+3$ where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are two natural numbers and $k_2>k_1$
From this we can deduce that $T_n-T_{n-1}$ is of the form $4\lambda+2$
I am stuck after this. I don't even know if I am going in the right direction.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Hint: You can try to work entirely modulo 4

You are trying to find numbers who obey certain conditions. After quite some search you don't seem to find them, and you conclude that you are stuck, but there is also another interpretation, as mentioned in B00n's answer :-)

Hint: As student91 suggests, working modulo 4 reveals a lot about the sequence as there are only 4 possible values for $T_n$.

$$(T_n \pmod 4)_{n\geq 1}  = (1,1,2,3,3,2,3,\dots)$$

from this it's quite easy to conclude
